# Why does gzipped html file display without JS and CSS?

Tags: javascript, html, css, compression, gzip

I have an html file saved in gzip format. The browser displays the html file but without the javascript and CSS. Non-zipped html files in the same directory do display correctly. In addition, I saved the source from the compressed html file and it reopened correctly, with JS and CSS applied.

What is different about displaying the zipped html that would not allow it to pick up the JS and CSS?

Comment: You are gzipping the file for transfer right? You didn't gzip locally and put that file on your server did you?

Comment: No I didn't. My cgi application zips the file to when it is executed. The files are then sitting on the server zipped, ready to be called. I am using an embedded web server and it doesn't support gzip or zipping on the fly.

Comment: If the html displays correctly, there must be something wrong with the JS and CSS references or URLs. Is there anything odd/different about the way your are including those files? (Of course it would be easiest if you could provide us with a public URL or code at least, waiting until someone guesses the problem is the slowest way to get an answer)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The basic problem is you can't just serve a gzip file where the browser expects CSS. By itself, that does not work any more than if you return a JPEG or a ham sandwich.

When content gets zipped on the fly, the response is somewhat different -- the response says "I am text/css, but, happen to be encoded with gzip for transfer". The browser can figure that one out.

Some web servers like Apache will do that sort of thing for you if you supply gzipped files locally, too. But I imagine your server isn't.

Why does it work for HTML? Hmm, I don't know, maybe your browser actually manages to figure it out in that particular case?

What you ultimately want to do is serve the response with Content-Type: text/css and Content-Encoding: gzip to have it recognized correctly.

Answer (score 2):

it you're working on Localhost on your own server (like XAMPP)

then you need to configure the .htaccess file to send the right

headers that said that files might be gziped.

try adding this to you main .htaccess file :

```
AddEncoding x-gzip .gz
AddType text/html .gz
```

and make sure your gziped compressed

files are endind with the **.gz** extention.

also, always run this in a server.. :)